# Merge sort an array of structs

Tags: c, sorting, segmentation-fault, mergesort

I'm trying to merge sort an array of structs, I've had many different seg faults but at the moment its happening in the `arrayCopy` function:

```
void arrayCopy(item10array dest[], item10array src[], const int lenght, const int leftShift) {
    for (int i = 0; i < lenght; i++) {
        structCopy(dest[i], src[leftShift + i]);
    }
}
```

I have changed small things until I pushed the seg fault into the function `arrayCopy`, I dont understand what is causing the error.

```
typedef struct 
{
    char Nome[50]; //vem do ficheiro ruas.txt
    unsigned int int_arr[6];
    char char_arr[6];
} Arteria;

typedef struct
{
    Arteria arteria;
    int cont;
} item10array;

void structCopy(item10array dest, item10array src) {

    strcpy(dest.arteria.Nome, src.arteria.Nome);

    for (int j = 0; j < 6; j++) {
        dest.arteria.int_arr[j] = src.arteria.int_arr[j];
        dest.arteria.char_arr[j] = src.arteria.char_arr[j];
    }

    dest.cont = src.cont;
}

void arrayCopy(item10array dest[], item10array src[], const int lenght, const int leftShift) {
    for (int i = 0; i < lenght; i++) {
        structCopy(dest[i], src[leftShift + i]);
    }
}

void mergeSorted(item10array *array, const int l, const int m, const int r) {
    int left_lenght = m - l + 1;
    int right_lenght = r - m;

    item10array temp_left[left_lenght];
    item10array temp_right[right_lenght];

    int i, j, k;

    arrayCopy(temp_left, array, left_lenght, l);
    arrayCopy(temp_right, array, right_lenght, m + 1);

    for (i = 0, j = 0, k = l; k <= r; k++) {
        if ((i < left_lenght) && (j >= right_lenght || temp_left[i].cont <= temp_right[j].cont)) {
            structCopy(array[k], temp_left[i]);
            i++;
        } else {
            structCopy(array[k], temp_right[j]);
            j++;
        }
    }  
}

void sortRecursion(item10array *arrray, int l, int r) {
    //isto é desnecessario mas dá me paz de alma
    if (r <= 1)
        return;
    if (l < r) {
        //encontrar o meio do array
        int m = l + (r - l) / 2;

        sortRecursion(arrray, l, m);
        sortRecursion(arrray, m + 1, r);

        mergeSorted(arrray, l, m, r);
    }
}

void sortItem10(item10array *rua, int lenght) {
    sortRecursion(rua, 0, lenght - 1);
}

void item10letra(Arteria *origin_ptr) {
    item10array rua[345] = {{"0", 0, 0, 0}};
    for (int i = 0; i < 345; i++) {
        rua[i].arteria = origin_ptr[i];
    }
    char letra;
    int cont = 0;
    int lenght = sizeof(item10array) * 345;

    for (int i = 0; i < 345; i++) {
        rua[i].arteria = origin_ptr[i];
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 345; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 6 && rua[i].arteria.char_arr[j] != 0; j++) {
            if (rua[i].arteria.char_arr[j] == letra) {
                cont++;
            }
        }
        rua[i].cont = cont;
    }

    sortItem10(rua, lenght);
}
```

Some things aren't named in English, that's because I'm also not named in English.

Thanks.

Comment: The compiler warns about `if(rua[i].arteria.char_arr[j] == letra)` because `char letra` is never assigned any value.

Comment: ... so the program's behaviour is undefined from there on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As posted, `structCopy` does not do anything useful because the `src` and `dest` structures are passed by value, so assigning the members of `src` to those of `dest` only modifies the function argument and has no effect on the structure arrays passed to `arrayCopy`.

Structures can be copied simply by assignment. Here is a modified version of `arrayCopy`:

```
void arrayCopy(item10array dest[], const item10array src[],
               int length, int leftShift) {
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        dest[i] = src[leftShift + i];
    }
}
```

The problem in your sort program is elsewhere:

- the `length` computed in `sortRecursion` is incorrect: `int length = sizeof(item10array) * 345;` is bogus as you multiply the size of the array in bytes by its hardcoded number of elements instead of dividing by the size of an array element:

  ```
  int length = sizeof(item10array) / sizeof(item10array[0]);
  ```
- also `char letra;` is not initialized to counting the occurrences of the letter in the artery names is meaningless.
- note also that using `r` as the index of the last element in the slice is also confusing. It is more idiomatic in C to use the index of the element past the end of the slice to avoid error prone `+1` / `-1` adjustments.

Here is a modified version of your code:

```
typedef struct {
    char Nome[50]; //vem do ficheiro ruas.txt
    unsigned int int_arr[6];
    char char_arr[6];
} Arteria;

typedef struct {
    Arteria arteria;
    int cont;
} item10array;

void arrayCopy(item10array dest[], const item10array src[],
               int length, int leftShift) {
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        dest[i] = src[leftShift + i];
    }
}

void mergeSorted(item10array *array, int l, int m, int r) {
    int left_length = m - l;
    int i, j, k;
    item10array temp_left[left_length];

    // only save the left part, elements in the right part are
    // never overwritten before they are copied.
    arrayCopy(temp_left, array, left_length, l);

    for (i = 0, j = m, k = l; k < r; k++) {
        if (i < left_length
        &&  (j >= r || temp_left[i].cont <= array[j].cont)) {
            array[k] = temp_left[i++];
        } else {
            array[k] = array[j++]);
        }
    }  
}

void sortRecursion(item10array *array, int l, int r) {
    if (r - l > 1) {
        // encontrar o meio do array
        int m = l + (r - l) / 2;

        sortRecursion(array, l, m);
        sortRecursion(array, m, r);
        mergeSorted(array, l, m, r);
    }
}

void sortItem10(item10array *rua, int length) {
    sortRecursion(rua, 0, length);
}

void item10letra(Arteria *origin_ptr) {
    item10array rua[345] = {{"0", 0, 0, 0}};
    int length = sizeof(item10array) / sizeof(item10array[0]);
    char letra = 'a';

    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        int cont = 0;
        rua[i].arteria = origin_ptr[i];
        for (int j = 0; j < 6 && rua[i].arteria.char_arr[j] != 0; j++) {
            if (rua[i].arteria.char_arr[j] == letra) {
                cont++;
            }
        }
        rua[i].cont = cont;
    }
    sortItem10(rua, length);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that was all the issue. I did think i could simply assign structs but after the seg faults i started thinking that might be the problem and then i didnt change it as i wanted to get to a solution first. Thank you for the help, sizeof(item10array) * 345 was really quite absurd

Answer (score 0):

Not a solution but you do not need to iterate through the array struct members at all. You can assign structs. (I would also suggest using `size_t` type instead of `int`)

```
void arrayCopy(item10array *dest, const item10array *src, const size_t lenght, const size_t leftShift) 
{
    for(size_t i = 0; i < lenght; i++) 
    {
        dest[i] = src[leftShift + i];
    }
}
```